# Symfony6 - add iput field after submitting form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony6

i have an ChoiceType::class input field in my form with, now just as an example, two choices:
'choices' => ['type1' => '1', 'type2' => '2']

now when the user select type2 i want to add an exta TextType::class inputfield to the form.
But i dont want to show the input field before and i want it to be required if selected type2 and not if selected type1.

I hope it make sense, i try it to to with javascript and set the attribute to hidden or not, but
then the form is not been send because of the required attribute.

I tried it with form events but did not get it to work in that way.

Thanks

Comment: in your js try to remove the required attribute when you are setting it to display none. Yes the form checks for the required attribute on input fields even when they are display:none despite them not being submitted. So according to that strategy, if the static html with their starting condition says "display:none" make sure that such initial condition starts from not having the required attribute at all (if you are not going to init that from scratch in a onload js event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were on the right way, you have to do it in Javascript. You just need to manage the attr required in Javascript so that the form does not block you with something like this:

- Remove the required attribute from a field: `document.getElementById("id").required = false;`
- Make a field required : `document.getElementById("id").required = true;`

And you can check if the form can be sumitted with : `document.getElementById("idForm").reportValidity();`.

Comment: Yes that worked for me thank you, just thought there is a "better elegant" way doing it with symfony itself.

Comment: Unfortunately, with the backend only, this is impossible.

Comment: Yre welcom ;) Do not hesitate to closed and vote to complete this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I using implementation of conditional fields with data-attributes, e.g.:

```
->add('typeField', EnumType::class, [
  'label' => 'Type',
  'class' => MyTypeEnum::Class,
])
->add('someField', TextField::class, [
  'data-controller' => 'depends-on',
  'data-depends-on' => 'my_form_typeField',
  'data-depends-value' => MyTypeEnum::OTHER->value,
])
```

On frontend JS stimulus controller show/hide someField depend on typeField value.
And validation() function in object ('data_class' in formType) make custom validation, e.g.:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
  if ($this->typeField !== MyTypeEnum::OTHER) {
    $context->buildViolation('message')->atPath('typeField')->addViolation();
  }
}
```